# Add external JS to Magento 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento2

I'm a front-end developer and don't have any access to Magento 2 admin panel.
I've created a custom plugin I would like to use and currently I'm adding external scripts to the plugin in the following way (works on every platform I tested except Magento 2) -

```
var cropperScript = document.createElement('script');
cropperScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.2.1/cropper.min.js');
document.head.appendChild(cropperScript);
var loadImageScript = document.createElement('script');
loadImageScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-load-image/2.19.0/load-image.all.min.js');
document.head.appendChild(loadImageScript);
```

However, in all the Magento 2 sites I've tested the external scripts appear in the sources tab but they are undefined.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Read [Official doc](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_css) for including static resources in Magento 2

Comment: As I wrote in the original post - I don't have access to the Magento 2 site or admin panel, I want to add the script without any access

Comment: You don't need to login to magento 2 admin, here is the answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156035/how-to-add-a-custom-javascript-to-theme-in-magento-2

Comment: Already tried the following -  
    require(['https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-load-image/2.19.0/load-image.all.min.js']); but getting the following error - Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module

Comment: Not enough details. Where did you added your code??

Answer (score 0):

if you can don't use external script, download it and :

1 - In your Theme Folder :

put the script.js in

```
app/design/frontend/theme/MyTheme/web/js/
```

2 - Create a layout to add your script

app/design/frontend/theme/MyTheme/Magento_Theme/layout

Create default.xml and add :

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="js/myscript.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

If you really need to be an external link do this in the layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.2.1/cropper.min.js" src_type="url"/>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-load-image/2.19.0/load-image.all.min.js" src_type="url"/>

    </head>
</page>
```